# Why PasswordChangeForm isn't valid?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

As i wrote in subject. I am working on password changing by logged in user, I am Django's newbie, and I can't find any good tutorial about PasswordChangeForm usage, therefore I am asking you to tell me how to create this form's object, properly, to make it valid. Here's my code, note that I am providing proper data (I've checked and old_password is valid), **old_password**, **new_password1**, **new_password2**. I paste here just backbone of my **password_change** function. I've modified it to see better, whether form is valid and what's happening. Thanks in advance for help.

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def password_change(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse("TRUE")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("FALSE")
    else:
        user = request.user
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=user)
        return render(request, 'account/password_change.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Pass `user=request.user` to the form too.

Comment: In this case, occurs error, about passing to many **user** values, when it requires one.

Comment: Are you sure? If you are logged in there's only one User in the request. Can you try and print out `user=request.user`?

Comment: As I remember I was trying do that and that error occured, I will check it again when I'll back home, and paste debug information here. Thanks.